# Getting diagonals of 2D numpy array that affect original array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array. I would like to modify it by creating an array of its diagonal elements and modifying the diagonal array so that those changes reflect on the original 2D array.

I have tried with:

```
>>> a = np.ones(shape=(3,3))
>>> d1 = a[np.diag_indices_from(a)]
>>> d1
array([1., 1., 1.])
>>> d1[0] = 2
>>> d1
array([2., 1., 1.])
>>>a
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
```

It can be seen that the changes do not affect the original array.

Is there any way to create a diagonal array that will also affect the original 2D array?

EDIT:
I get the effect I'm looking for when I work with rows or columns:

```
>>> row0 = a[0]
>>> row0[0] = 0
>>> a
array([[0., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
>>> column0=a[:,0]
>>> column0[2]=3
>>> a
array([[0., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [3., 1., 1.]])
```

Comment: If the diagonal indexing uses arrays (advanced) then the values are a copy.  But I believe it is possible to use `strides` on a ravelled array, and get a view.  I'd have work out the details later.

Comment: @hpaulj using strides is possible (and what `einsum("ii->i",...` does); only it is important not to ravel the array before, because there are cases where ravelling does force an unnecessary (for extracting the diagonal) copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.einsum` to get precisely what you want:

> .. versionadded:: 1.10.0
>
> ```
> Views returned from einsum are now writeable whenever the input array
> is writeable. For example, ``np.einsum('ijk...->kji...', a)`` will now
> have the same effect as :py:func:`np.swapaxes(a, 0, 2) <numpy.swapaxes>`
> and ``np.einsum('ii->i', a)`` will return a writeable view of the diagonal
> of a 2D array.
> ```

```
a = np.ones((3,3))
b = np.einsum("ii->i",a)
b[:] = 2,3,4
a
# array([[2., 1., 1.],
#        [1., 3., 1.],
#        [1., 1., 4.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

When you index like that ([fancy indexing](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.07-fancy-indexing.html)) you are [getting a copy not a view](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html#I-think-I-understand-what-a-view-is,-but-why-fancy-indexing-is-not-returning-a-view?). You just need to assign `d1` back to `a` the same way you defined it

```py
a = np.ones(shape=(3,3))
d1 = a[np.diag_indices_from(a)]
d1[0] = 2
a[np.diag_indices_from(a)] = d1
```

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do it is using `np.diagonal` and `np.fill_diagonal`. There is a way to twist numpy that is added below as well:

```
a = np.ones(shape=(3,3))
d1 = np.diagonal(a).copy()
d1[0] = 2
np.fill_diagonal(a,d1)
```

output:

```
a

[[2. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
```

Note that based on [numpy doc for `np.diagonal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html): *Starting in NumPy 1.9 it returns a read-only view on the original array. Attempting to write to the resulting array will produce an error.
In some future release, it will return a read/write view and writing to the returned array will alter your original array. The returned array will have the same type as the input array.*

In order to twist numpy, you can do this, but I would suggest using above solution:

```
a = np.ones(shape=(3,3))
d1 = np.diagonal(a)
d1.setflags(True)
d1[0] = 2
np.fill_diagonal(a,d1)
```

output:

```
a

[[2. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
```

Answer (score 1):

With basic indexing of a flattened version of the array, it is possible:

```
In [150]: a = np.ones((3,3))                                                                         
In [151]: d1 = a.ravel()[::4]                                                                        
In [152]: d1[0] *= 2                                                                                 
In [153]: a                                                                                          
Out[153]: 
array([[2., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
In [154]: d1[:] = [1,2,3]                                                                            
In [155]: a                                                                                          
Out[155]: 
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 2., 1.],
       [1., 1., 3.]])
```

`np.diag` sort of does this, but sets the result to read-only.

```
In [157]: np.diag(a)                                                                                 
Out[157]: array([1., 2., 3.])
In [158]: d2 = np.diag(a)                                                                            
In [159]: d2[1] = 0                                                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-159-64d5edb77b4c> in <module>
----> 1 d2[1] = 0

ValueError: assignment destination is read-only
In [160]: a[1,1] = 10                                                                                
In [161]: a                                                                                          
Out[161]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1., 10.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  3.]])
In [162]: d2                                                                                         
Out[162]: array([ 1., 10.,  3.])
In [163]: d1                                                                                         
Out[163]: array([ 1., 10.,  3.])
```

Modifying `a` changes `d2`, but we can't do it the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not.  A NumPy array is a class object, with it's own indexing interface.  When you create a diagonal (a vector) as a separate object, you break that original indexing paradigm and replace it with another -- the vector is a separate object.

If you want this functionality, you *could* write your own class, creating a new `element` object for each matrix element.  Then you can readily alter those elements (through the class methods), changing the element value, but keeping the element instance intact.

This way, whenever you extract a diagonal -- or any other matrix slice, reference, etc. -- you work with the original object, not an immutable value.

Comment: Somehow it works for rows (and columns):
```
>>> row0 = a[0]
>>> row0[0] = 0
>>> a
array([[0., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
```
I was looking for that same functionality but with diagonal elements.

Comment: Rows and columns have slicing overlays built into NumPy.  There is no multi-dimensional overlay.  There is also no overlay for a slice with a "step" argument. The last language I knew to do that was a far precursor to MATLAB, several decades ago.

Comment: I understand. In that case it appears it's not possible to get the functionality I'm looking for directly from numpy.

Comment: Right.  I wish I could remember the name of that old language, but it was too long ago.

Comment: @prune, are you thinking of `APL`, a mathematical array language dating back to the 60s.

Comment: @hpaulj: no, this was a language designed and supported through U of Illinois and Argonne National Laboratory.  The name was something like FORmula, I think.  I think the interpreter was written in PL/I.  I do recall that all of the support functions were FORTRAN IV routines with a standard block of 14 parameters holding the session state.